# how to check if multiple elements exist in JavaScript/Flask

Tags: javascript

I have a js file with button click event listeners. The problem is those buttons do not exist until flask sends the data over. I want to only run the listeners if the elements exists or when the elements exist.

I am trying to solve this error that occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

HTML file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    {% if var %}
        <div>
         <h1>Hello {{var}}</h1>
         <button id="1">Click me</button>
         <button id="2">Click me</button>
         <button id="3">Click me</button>
         <button id="4">Click me</button>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <script async src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/buttons.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
<html>
```

JS file:

```
var Btn1Element = document.getElementById("1");
var Btn2Element = document.getElementById("2");
var Btn3Element = document.getElementById("3");
var Btn4Element = document.getElementById("4");

Btn1Element.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => {
      window.location = "/1";
  },
  false
);

Btn2Element.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => {
      window.location = "/2";
  },
  false
);

Btn3Element.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => {
      window.location = "/3";
  },
  false
);

Btn4Element.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => {
      window.location = "/4";
  },
  false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [async attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) on script, a script that will be run asynchronously as soon as it is available **while the page continues the parsing.**

It needs to wait and run after page loaded for *document.getElementById()*

Try to update as like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // your js code on here
  var Btn1Element = document.getElementById("1");
  ...
});
```

or you could remove async attribute on script tag.

**EDITED:**

check whether `{% if var %}` is true on your context.

i think it is not about javascript. html tags(elements) do not created by flask view engine by if condition.

[live on here](https://repl.it/repls/MixedSereneInternet#templates/index.html) and you could check what is different from yours

Comment: I tried this method with and without async and i tried to just remove async none of them worked. Thank for your help though.

Comment: @goosegoose then did you check the `{% if var %}` is true?

Comment: Yes I did. I was able to solve the error by putting the script tags in the {% if var %}  block but i was l looking for a javascript solution.

Comment: @goosegoose i think it is not about javascript. html tags(elements) do not created by flask view engine. [live on here](https://repl.it/repls/MixedSereneInternet#templates/index.html) and you could check what is different from yours.